# Why does DatePicker in Flutter InAppWebView look old?

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, flutter-dependencies, flutter-inappwebview

I am creating a Flutter application that consists of displaying a simple webview using the InAppWebView 6.0.0 dependency with the latest stable version of Flutter.
It's happening to me that when I go to enter data of type "date" on the website, a date selection interface that is quite ugly and obsolete opens up.

[image: screenshot]

I have also tested it using the normal webview and there yes is visible the modern date selection interface. I have made sure that the style is configured correctly and nothing is either.
I have also been able to see that on iPhone with the same configuration it looks good.

I would like to know if anyone else has had this problem and found the solution without having to touch the side of the web page :)

I have made sure that the style is correctly configured and the dependencies are in the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flutter_inappwebview` package uses [PlatformViews](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/android/platform-views), which requires you to add Android's Material dependency if you want to enable Material Design.

In `android/app/build.gradle`, add this implementation to the dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    // ...
}
```

Replace `<version>` with the latest version of the plugin, which you can find [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material).

---

See also:

- [Related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100067)
- [Enabling Material Components](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-material-components)

Comment: At first, I followed your advice by adding the dependency implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0") and editing the file app > src > main > res > value > style.xml. It seemed like it wasn't working, but then I realized there were other style.xml files that I needed to modify as well. The issue has been resolved now. Thank you very much!